# Kotlin refuses to pass parameter

Tags: json, api, kotlin

I'm pulling my hair out with this one and I'm hoping it's something obvious that someone can spot immediately.

I have a simple app that allows me and my kids to track our board game playing (we have a trophy and everything!). The app allows us to create a game, define the players and them upload the scores. Nice and simple.

I have written a simple API to add the games directly into the SQL Server database via json using retrofit.

This has all been working just fine until today. I want to know who creates/updates the game so I am getting the Google account details when the app launches. This works fine and I can store the email address in the global variables in Main Activity and read it back in the activity that creates the game (CreateNewGame).

I have set up an interface to make the call and I have the model defining the json. The stored proc takes the json and deals with it internally (yes, I know, not very secure but it's my kids and I, not a public app).

The problem is the call is being made and the game created, but the email address is not getting passed.

The model looks like this:

```
data class newGame(
  var gamename: String? = null,
  var email: String? = null,
  var event_id: Int? = 0,
  var gamedate: String? = "1900-01-01",
  var players: ArrayList<Player> = ArrayList()
) {
  data class Player(
    var player: String? = null,
    var player_id: Int? = 0,
    var score: Int? = 0,
    var points: Int? = 0
  )
}
```

My Interface is:

```
interface CreateGame {
    @POST("games?apitoken=xxxx")

    fun addNewGame(
        @Query("operation") operation: String,
        @Body newGame: newGame
    ): Call<gameEvent>

    companion object {

        fun create(): CreateGame {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BaseURL)
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(CreateGame::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

I call this from a function called from the button listener:

```
var gm: newGame = newGame(
    gamename = GamesList.text.toString(),
    email = GameTrackerApplication.currentUser
)

Log.d(GameTrackerApplication.TAG, "Creating game for ${gm.email!!}")

        //Add the game
        CreateGame.create().addNewGame("game", gm).enqueue(object: Callback<gameEvent> {

          override fun onFailure(call: Call<gameEvent>, t: Throwable) {
              Log.d(GameTrackerApplication.TAG, "ERROR:: ${t.localizedMessage!!}")
              t.printStackTrace()
          }

          override fun onResponse(call: Call<gameEvent>, response: Response<gameEvent>) {
              Log.d(GameTrackerApplication.TAG, gm.toString())
              Log.d(GameTrackerApplication.TAG, response.body()?.APIResult!![0].toString())

              var ev = response.body()?.APIResult!![0]
              var EventID: Int? = ev.games[0].event_id
              Log.d(GameTrackerApplication.TAG, "Event: ${EventID.toString()}")                  

              val intent = Intent(this@AddNewGame, Scorecard::class.java)
              intent.putExtra("EventID",EventID.toString())
              startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
```

I can see the message in the logcat that I write immediately after setting the game class "Creating game for tim@gmail.com" and I can see the two messages returned in the onResponse. The first writes the model including the email:

```
2021-09-16 11:07:36.092 27486-27486/? D/GameTrackerTAG: newGame(gamename=Ticket To Ride, email=tim@gmail.com, event_id=0, gamedate=1900-01-01, players=[Player(player=Tim, player_id=0, score=0, points=0), Player(player=Cin, player_id=0, score=0, points=0)])
```

and the second writes the response from the DB:

```
2021-09-16 11:07:36.092 27486-27486/? D/GameTrackerTAG: Result(developer_message=, games=[Game(event_date=2021-09-16, event_id=223, game_event_player_id=758, game_name=Ticket To Ride, player_id=1, player_name=Tim, score=0), Game(event_date=2021-09-16, event_id=223, game_event_player_id=759, game_name=Ticket To Ride, player_id=2, player_name=Cin, score=0)], id=200, status_message=Success, user_message=Success)
```

So I can see the event is created in the database. However, when I run SQL profiler I see:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the parameter "email" is not there!

The full call is:

```
exec dbo.NewEvent @NewGame=N'{"event_id":0,"gamename":"Ticket To Ride","gamedate":"1900-01-01","players":[{"player":"Tim","player_id":0,"score":0,"points":0},{"player":"Cin","player_id":0,"score":0,"points":0}]}'
```

I can't see what's preventing it being provided since the rest of the json goes in nicely. I've tried passing all the parameters rather than using the defaults and they all get passed just fine. I've tried changing the order of the parameters. I even read the global variable into a local string just in case it's something weird in the way that global variables are managed, but it just refuses to pass the email, which makes me think it must be something simple that I've missed.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just a wild stab in the dark: could there be a version mismatch somewhere, using an older version of `newGame` without that param, or an older version of the code serialising or deserialising it?

Comment: Is there a way to force Android Studio to update to the correct version? The API doesn't define the json, it just treats it as a string. SQL Server manipulates this string as json and ignores any elements that it doesn't care about. The string shown in profiler though doesn't have email so it's dropped out somewhere between Android and the DB call